# Magento 2.2 registration.phtml dob field calendar not loading

Tags: magento2.2, registration

I have a Magento 2.2 based dev site setup, I enabled the dob field via the admin panel so now the customer registration form registration.phtml shows the date of birth field. however when you click on the dob text box no calendar is shown and there is no button under the text input to make the calendar/datepicker show up??

Below is my register.phtml file

```
<?php if ($_dob->isEnabled()): ?>
        <?php //echo $_dob->setDate($block->getFormData()->getDob())->toHtml() ?>
        <div class="field date field-dob required">
             <label class="label" for="dob"><span>Date of Birth</span></label>
             <div class="control customer-dob">
               <input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" class="_has-datepicker" data-validate="{required:true}" autocomplete="off" aria-required="true" />
                                    <button type="button" class="ui-datepicker-trigger v-middle"><span>Select Date</span></button>
                                    <script>
                                        require([
                                            "jquery",
                                            "mage/calendar"
                                        ], function($){
                                            $("#dob").calendar({
                                                buttonText:"<?php echo __('Select Date') ?>",
                                            });
                                        });
                                    </script>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Jayreis, Did you find any solution of this issue?

Comment: I wound up just replacing the field with a jquery ui date field input since i could not find what was causing it not to work.